# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: momentProvider <- moment (Jasmine Test Case)

Tags: momentjs, karma-jasmine, angular-moment

I am trying to write a test case for a directive using moment in angular but i am getting below error:-

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: momentProvider <- moment

Can someone please help with how to include moment module in jasmine